# PHP contact form message box

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have a contact form code, but I cannot figure out where to change the message box width, so its not a custom-expanding and is limited in width?

http://s197371217.websitehome.co.uk/try/contact.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use normal CSS for that using

```
textarea {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none /* disables resizing */
}
```

Comment: Technically correct, but please don't disable user resizing. It's a useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method.

```
<textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea>
```

You can change the numbers in `rows` and `cols` to get it just right, or you can use `hex4's` method.